# Explicitly addressing an Intent to a dynamically registered broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am new to Android and trying to understand the communication between apps.

I am trying to write 3 little apps which can communicate with each other. If you want to send a message to everybody, you just use an implicit broadcast.

**implicit Intent** `intent.setAction("com.example.myChatMessage")`

If you want to address only 1 specific receiver, I did it with

**explicit Intent** `intent.setComponent("com.example.test.android.broadcastreceiver.b", "com.example.test.android.broadcastreceiver.b.myBroadcastReceiver")`

This works when the broadcast receiver is a seperate class and defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**My Question:** Is it possible to *explicitly address a dynamically registered broadcast receiver*?

package com.example.test.android.broadcastreceiver.b;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```java
package com.example.test.android.broadcastreceiver.b;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final IntentFilter intentfilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.myChatMessage");
    private myBroadcastReceiver broadcastreceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        broadcastreceiver = new myBroadcastReceiver();
        registerReceiver(broadcastreceiver, intentfilter);
    }

    public static class myBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            Log.d("message", "B received: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

It receives all implicit broadcasts but no explicit one — I don't know how to address it. Can you help me?

Comment: Using the method: `intent.setPackage("com.example.test.android.broadcastreceiver.b")` works to explicit address the application and then using the implicit intent resolution. Due to a bug [link](https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/intents-mobisys11.pdf) you should use it only with Android 4.0 `Alternatively, starting with ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH, you can also safely restrict the broadcast to a single application with Intent.setPackage`

Comment: Only found one paper [link](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/andsurf-spsm12.pdf) that says: `However, Dynamic
Receivers (Broadcast Receivers declared at runtime) are an
exception, since some can only receive implicit Intents. Thus,
they are always public, and Intents they receive must match
one of their Intent Filters.` Which one can receive an explicit one?

Answer (score 22):

It does not appear possible to send an explicit intent to a dynamically registered broadcast receiver. Registering the receiver in AndroidManifest.xml is the only way.

> If you dynamically register a BroadcastReceiver – by calling Context.registerReceiver() – you supply a BroadcastReceiver *instance* ... If you try to send an Intent to the receiver by naming the class of the BroadcastReceiver, it will never get delivered .. The Android system will not match the Intent you declared to the class of the BroadcastReceiver instance you registered.

Source: http://onemikro2nd.blogspot.com/2013/09/darker-corners-of-android.html