# Is it possible to register a receiver in a test case?

Tags: java, android, testing, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to test inside a unit test whether or not an alarm programmed using the `AlarmManager` is fired, and if so, if it is fired within the correct period.

Here is the receiver class to be tested.
I've created it inside my test project.
(NOTE: it's not registered in the manifest)

```
public class MockBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int numTimesCalled = 0;

    MockBroadcastReceiver(){
        numTimesCalled = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        numTimesCalled++;           
    }

    public static int getNumTimesCalled() {
        return numTimesCalled;
    }

    public static void setNumTimesCalled(int numTimesCalled) {
        MockBroadcastReceiver.numTimesCalled = numTimesCalled;
    }
}
```

And here's the unit test. The `programReceiver` method actually belongs to a class in the main project, but I've included it inside the test so that you don't need to read so much code.

```
public class ATest extends AndroidTestCase {

    MockBroadcastReceiver mockReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockReceiver = new MockBroadcastReceiver();
        getContext().registerReceiver(mockReceiver, new IntentFilter());
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() {     
        getContext().unregisterReceiver(mockReceiver);
        mockReceiver = null;
    }


    public void test(){
        //We're going to program twice and check that only the last
        //programmed alarm should remain active.

        final Object flag = new Object();
        MockBroadcastReceiver.setNumTimesCalled(0);

        new Thread (){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                programReceiver(getContext(), MockBroadcastReceiver.class, 60000, 60000);

                SystemClock.sleep(20000);

                programReceiver(getContext(), MockBroadcastReceiver.class, 60000, 60000);

                SystemClock.sleep(90000);

                synchronized(flag){
                    flag.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        synchronized(flag){
            try {
                flag.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        assertEquals(1, MockBroadcastReceiver.getNumTimesCalled()); //should have been called at least once, but its 0.
    }


    private static void programReceiver(Context context, Class<? extends BroadcastReceiver> receiverClass, long initialDelay, long period){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, receiverClass);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);     

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); //Cancel any previous alarm

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating (
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis() + initialDelay,
            period,
            pendingIntent
        );
    }   
}
```

When I execute the `test` method, the receiver should have been registered dynamically in the `setUp`. Then I program the same alarm twice. My intent was to test that only the last alarm remained active, but I'm having trouble getting the receiver called at all. The test fails as it is expected to be called once (or at least a number of times >= 1), but the counter in the mock receiver is 0. I've set a break point in the `onReceive` method and it is never hit. I've also added logging and nothing shows in the logcat. So I'm 100% sure the receiver is not being called. I've also tried increasing the sleep time in the thread, because `setInexactRepeating` fires very inexactly, but I can wait for ages and it is still not called.

I've also tried registering it in the test project's manifest instead of programmatically and the results are the same.

Why is the receiver not being called?

---

UPDATE
**I can confirm the `AlarmManager` is not the issue**. Alarms are correctly registered according to adb dumpsys alarm.

I'm now trying to get the receiver to run by calling `sendBroadcast`, but I'm in a dead end. The receiver just won't get called. I tried the main app context, the test case context, even `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. Tried also adding WakeLocks and nothing. There's just no way of getting it called. I think this might be caused by some flags in the intent or intent filter (android seems to be really picky with flags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is yes, it is possible, BUT receivers will only work with implicit (action-based) Intents and IntentFilters.

Explicit intents (class based, with no filters) don't work with dynamically registered receivers. For explicit intents to work, you need to register the receiver in the manifest, and not dynamically as I was trying to do.

This is one of the darkest and least documented features of Android. In my experience with intents, you can never be sure. And it's also very difficult to diagnose, as there's no warning printed in the logcat that could help understand the problem. Kudos to @d2vid's answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482865

So to fix my code I'd have to add the receiver element inside the application tag in the manifest. As the receiver is a mock receiver class created inside the test project, I'd have to edit the test project manifest, not the main project one. But on the other hand, in Eclipse test projects, receiver tags added to the manifest don't seem to work. Android Studio looks better suited for manifest merging, but this is a legacy project started in Eclipse and we are not porting it.

In conclusion: explicit intent testing is broken in Eclipse for those receivers that don't exist in the main project. The class I needed to test uses only explicit intents so my test can't be written in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

In the android source-code there is a [alarmManagerTest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/e49374b36f20d87119b0d16665757ebe9f841358/tests/tests/app/src/android/app/cts/AlarmManagerTest.java) that executes alarmManager.setInexactRepeating with a broadcastreceiver.

The main difference is that the working android test has a delay of 15 minutes while your test uses 1 minute delay.

The Android documentation for [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) says:

```
 public void setInexactRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)
```

...
intervalMillis  interval in milliseconds between subsequent repeats of the alarm. Prior to API 19, if this is one of INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, or INTERVAL_DAY then the alarm will be phase-aligned with other alarms to reduce the number of wakeups. Otherwise, the alarm will be set as though the application had called setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent). As of API 19, all repeating alarms will be inexact and subject to batching with other alarms regardless of their stated repeat interval.

I am not shure if this means that only multibles of 15 minutes are allowed.

On my Android 2.2 handset the inexact timer only works if it is a multible of 15 minutes.

Comment: AlarmManager is not the problem. There's something at a lower level preventing the receiver from being called. Read my update.

Comment: Despite not being the correct answer, the bounty is well deserved as the test you linked showed me the only difference from my code was the use of implicit intents and intent filters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your test is not working as expected. A couple of suggestions spring to mind:

1. Most of the doco I've seen, eg. [1], suggests that `Object.wait()` should always be called within a loop based on a condition that does not hold. Your code does not do this. Perhaps you could try re-working it so that it does.
2. For completeness, perhaps you should output something for the `InterruptedException` that can be thrown by `flag.wait()` just in case.

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--

Comment: While I agree the synchronization code could be better, It will work in 99,99% of the cases and it is ok for a dirty unit test.