# How to stop my service after passing fixed amount of time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

At point A in my application I start my service and expect the service get closed from point B. However, there might be few scenarios that point B doesn't ask service to get closed. In this case I want the service close itself after fixed amount of time.

I have written following code into my Service class and expect the service gets closed after 10 seconds from launch time (It will be 45min in the future but I don't want to stay that long for test).

```
public class ChatService extends Service implements ITCPConnection
{
    private static final int SERVICE_LIFE_TIME = 10 * 1000; // In millis

    private AlarmReceiver mAlarmReceiver;
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        //
        mAlarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mAlarmReceiver, new IntentFilter());

        //
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + SERVICE_LIFE_TIME, alarmIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy()");

        // Unregister receiver
        if (mAlarmReceiver != null)
        {
            unregisterReceiver(mAlarmReceiver);
        }

        disconnect();
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        // If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
        if (alarmMgr!= null)
        {
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }

        ...

        Log.e(TAG, "disconnect()");
    }


    /*****************
     * Alarm Receiver
     *****************/
    private static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Stop service from AlarmReceiver");
            context.stopService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is `AlarmReceiver.onReceive()` never gets called and therefore my service will be alive indefinitely.

Comment: only 10 seconds? You could try to use a `android.os.Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long);` instead

Comment: @Budius, haha its exact time will be 30min or 45min, I just don't want to stay this long for testing :) I just updated my question.

Comment: I believe there issue here is that the alarm  manager (specially on later versions of the OS) is not so exact as it is always trying to be nice on the battery. You could setup some tests to run over night, but alternatively, use the 'Application.ActivityLifeCycleCallbacks' to let your service known there's no more activities.

Comment: @Hesam A wild and naive guess, but have you tried setting `requestCode` to something other than `0`?

Comment: @SqueezyMo, thanks, just tested it with `100`, same result. Receiver never gets called :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to targeting a broadcast receiver explicitly.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810134/explicit-addressing-an-intent-to-a-dynamically-broadcast-receiver), it cannot be done over a dinamically created (i.e. not declared into the manifest) broadcast receiver, because the os would not know how to resolve it.
To check if this is the root of the problem, you can go with the implicit way and set an action inside the [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29) and by filtering it in the IntentFilter.

Anyway, using the post delayed can be seen as a valid alternative, since you expect the service to be shut down naturally or still be around to intercept the delayed event.

Another (unrelated) thing is that you are calling

```
            context.stopService(intent);
```

by using the broadcast intent and not the intent that started the service. You could simply call `stopSelf()`.

Comment: Awesome dude, thanks. the problem was exactly that. Also correct for stopSelfe().

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)

Comment: Just to complete the answer I put `((ChatService) mContext).stopSelf();` in `onReceive()` method. App works fine and `stopSelf()` gets called but `onDestroy()` never gets called. Any idea? I set `mContext = this` in `onCreate()` of service.